# tf.keras.models.load_model raise TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: tensorflow, keras, object-detection-api

I am working on a pipeline of object_detection network with ssd_mobilenet. This network contains tf Object_Detection API and ssd_keras repo(doesn't matter).
Now the problem is that I want to save and load the whole model, including **weights**,**optimizer**,**loss_infos** so I want to use `model.save` . But when I use `tf.keras.models.load_model('save_path')`, it raises this error.
here is my model definition:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

# this script is define the ssd_mobilenet model
# from object_dection and keras-ssd models

from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Activation, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D, Reshape, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from my_model.feature_extractors import choose_feature_extractor
import numpy as np

from ssd_keras.keras_layers.keras_layer_AnchorBoxes import AnchorBoxes
from ssd_keras.keras_layers.keras_layer_L2Normalization import L2Normalization
from ssd_keras.keras_layers.keras_layer_DecodeDetections import DecodeDetections
from ssd_keras.keras_layers.keras_layer_DecodeDetectionsFast import DecodeDetectionsFast

# to enable the version problem
# don't know why
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
L2_REG = 0.00004

def class_conf(out_dim, name, **kwargs):
    # predict n_classes confidence values for each box
    if not kwargs:
        return Conv2D(out_dim, (3,3), padding='same', 
            kernel_initializer='he_normal', kernel_regularizer=l2(L2_REG), name=name)
    return Conv2D(out_dim, (3,3), padding='same', 
            kernel_initializer='he_normal', kernel_regularizer=l2(L2_REG), name=name)(kwargs['input'])

def box_cord(out_dim, name, **kwargs):
    # predict 4 box coordinates for each box
    if not kwargs:
        return Conv2D(out_dim, (3,3), padding='same', 
            kernel_initializer='he_normal', kernel_regularizer=l2(L2_REG), name=name)
    return Conv2D(out_dim, (3,3), padding='same', 
            kernel_initializer='he_normal', kernel_regularizer=l2(L2_REG), name=name)(kwargs['input'])


def ssd_model(image_size,
                n_classes,
                base_model,
                is_training=True,
                aspect_ratios_global=None,
                two_boxes_for_ar1=True,
                scales=None,
                aspect_ratios_per_layer=None,
                steps=[8,6,32,64,100,300],
                clip_boxes=False,
                variances=[0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2],
                coords='centroids',
                normalize_coords=True,
                offsets=None,
                iou_threshold=0.50,
                confidence_thresh=0.01,
                top_k=200,
                nms_max_output_size=400,
                fine_tuning=False):

    n_predictor_layers = 6
    n_classes += 1
    img_height, img_width, img_channels = image_size[0], image_size[1], image_size[2] 

    # define aspect_ratios and num_boxes
    if aspect_ratios_per_layer:
        aspect_ratios = aspect_ratios_per_layer
    else:
        aspect_ratios = [aspect_ratios_global] * n_predictor_layers

    if aspect_ratios_per_layer:
        n_boxes = []
        for ar in aspect_ratios_per_layer:
            if (1 in ar) & two_boxes_for_ar1:
                n_boxes.append(len(ar) + 1) # +1 for the second box for aspect ratio 1
            else:
                n_boxes.append(len(ar))
    else: # If only a global aspect ratio list was passed, then the number of boxes is the same for each predictor layer
        if (1 in aspect_ratios_global) & two_boxes_for_ar1:
            n_boxes = len(aspect_ratios_global) + 1
        else:
            n_boxes = len(aspect_ratios_global)
        n_boxes = [n_boxes] * n_predictor_layers
    # used to instantiate a keras tensorm, a symbolic tensor object

    X = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, img_channels))
    # Backbone
    feature_extractor = choose_feature_extractor(base_model=base_model,
                                        is_training=is_training,
                                        fine_tuning=fine_tuning)

    resized_image = feature_extractor.preprocess(X)
    feature_maps = feature_extractor(resized_image)

    conf_1 = class_conf(out_dim=n_boxes[0]*n_classes, name='conf_1', input=feature_maps[0])
    conf_2 = class_conf(out_dim=n_boxes[1]*n_classes, name='conf_2', input=feature_maps[1])
    conf_3 = class_conf(out_dim=n_boxes[2]*n_classes, name='conf_3', input=feature_maps[2])
    conf_4 = class_conf(out_dim=n_boxes[3]*n_classes, name='conf_4', input=feature_maps[3])
    conf_5 = class_conf(out_dim=n_boxes[4]*n_classes, name='conf_5', input=feature_maps[4])
    conf_6 = class_conf(out_dim=n_boxes[5]*n_classes, name='conf_6', input=feature_maps[5])

    loc_1 = box_cord(out_dim=n_boxes[0]*4, name='loc_1', input=feature_maps[0])
    loc_2 = box_cord(out_dim=n_boxes[1]*4, name='loc_2', input=feature_maps[1])
    loc_3 = box_cord(out_dim=n_boxes[2]*4, name='loc_3', input=feature_maps[2])
    loc_4 = box_cord(out_dim=n_boxes[3]*4, name='loc_4', input=feature_maps[3])
    loc_5 = box_cord(out_dim=n_boxes[4]*4, name='loc_5', input=feature_maps[4])
    loc_6 = box_cord(out_dim=n_boxes[5]*4, name='loc_6', input=feature_maps[5])

    box_1 = AnchorBoxes(img_height, img_width, this_scale=scales[0], next_scale=scales[1], aspect_ratios=aspect_ratios[0],
                                             two_boxes_for_ar1=two_boxes_for_ar1, this_steps=steps[0], this_offsets=offsets[0], clip_boxes=clip_boxes,
                                             variances=variances, coords=coords, normalize_coords=normalize_coords, name='box_1')(loc_1)
    box_2 = AnchorBoxes(img_height, img_width, this_scale=scales[1], next_scale=scales[2], aspect_ratios=aspect_ratios[1],
                                    two_boxes_for_ar1=two_boxes_for_ar1, this_steps=steps[1], this_offsets=offsets[1], clip_boxes=clip_boxes,
                                    variances=variances, coords=coords, normalize_coords=normalize_coords, name='box_2')(loc_2)
    box_3 = AnchorBoxes(img_height, img_width, this_scale=scales[2], next_scale=scales[3], aspect_ratios=aspect_ratios[2],
                                        two_boxes_for_ar1=two_boxes_for_ar1, this_steps=steps[2], this_offsets=offsets[2], clip_boxes=clip_boxes,
                                        variances=variances, coords=coords, normalize_coords=normalize_coords, name='box_3')(loc_3)
    box_4 = AnchorBoxes(img_height, img_width, this_scale=scales[3], next_scale=scales[4], aspect_ratios=aspect_ratios[3],
                                        two_boxes_for_ar1=two_boxes_for_ar1, this_steps=steps[3], this_offsets=offsets[3], clip_boxes=clip_boxes,
                                        variances=variances, coords=coords, normalize_coords=normalize_coords, name='box_4')(loc_4)
    box_5 = AnchorBoxes(img_height, img_width, this_scale=scales[4], next_scale=scales[5], aspect_ratios=aspect_ratios[4],
                                        two_boxes_for_ar1=two_boxes_for_ar1, this_steps=steps[4], this_offsets=offsets[4], clip_boxes=clip_boxes,
                                        variances=variances, coords=coords, normalize_coords=normalize_coords, name='box_5')(loc_5)
    box_6 = AnchorBoxes(img_height, img_width, this_scale=scales[5], next_scale=scales[6], aspect_ratios=aspect_ratios[5],
                                        two_boxes_for_ar1=two_boxes_for_ar1, this_steps=steps[5], this_offsets=offsets[5], clip_boxes=clip_boxes,
                                        variances=variances, coords=coords, normalize_coords=normalize_coords, name='box_6')(loc_6)

    # reshape
    confs = [conf_1, conf_2, conf_3, conf_4, conf_5, conf_6]
    locs = [loc_1, loc_2, loc_3, loc_4, loc_5, loc_6]
    boxes = [box_1, box_2, box_3, box_4, box_5, box_6]
    for i, value in enumerate(confs):
        confs[i] = Reshape((-1, n_classes), name='conf_reshape_'+str(i))(value)
    for i, value in enumerate(locs):
        locs[i] = Reshape((-1, 4), name='loc_reshape_'+str(i))(value)
    for i,value in enumerate(boxes):
        boxes[i] = Reshape((-1, 8), name='box_reshape_'+str(i))(value)
    
    mbox_conf = Concatenate(axis=1, name='mbox_conf')(confs)
    mbox_loc = Concatenate(axis=1, name='mbox_loc')(locs)
    mbox_priorbox = Concatenate(axis=1, name='mbox_priorbox')(boxes)

    mbox_conf_softmax = Activation('softmax', name='mbox_conf_softmax')(mbox_conf)
    predictions = Concatenate(axis=2, name='predictions')([mbox_conf_softmax, mbox_loc, mbox_priorbox])

    if is_training:
        model = Model(inputs=X, outputs=predictions)

    return model
```

and feature_extractor is a **subclass Model** in object_detection API defined in *ssd_mobilenet_v2_keras_feature_extractor.py*.
I noticed that to enable `model.save()` I need to overwrite **get_config()** function in Model subclass. But I don't know what to add, so I just add parameters in self.parameters follow some tutorials, like this:

```
## in ssd_meta_arch.SSDKerasFeatureExtractor
def get_config(self):
        return {'is_training': self._is_training,
                'depth_multiplier': self._depth_multiplier,
                'min_depth': self._min_depth,
                'pad_to_multiple': self._pad_to_multiple,
                # 'conv_hyperparams': self._conv_hyperparams,  # raise TypeError: 'Not JSON Serializable:' 
                'freeze_batchnorm': self._freeze_batchnorm,
                'inplace_batchnorm_update': self._inplace_batchnorm_update,
                'use_explicit_padding': self._use_explicit_padding,
                'use_depthwise': self._use_depthwise,
                'num_layers': self._num_layers,
                'override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams': self._override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams}
```

```
## in SSDMobileNetV2KerasFeatureExtractor
def get_config(self):
        config = super(SSDMobileNetV2KerasFeatureExtractor, self).get_config()
        config.update({'fine_tuning':self.fine_tuning,
                      #  'classification_backbone':self.classification_backbone,
                      #  'feature_map_generator':self.feature_map_generator
                      })
        
        return config
```

I can save the model via `ModelCheckpoint(save_weights_only=False,...)` but when load I met this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 37, in <module>
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(args.load_checkpoint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 207, in load_model
    return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 158, in load
    keras_loader.finalize_objects()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 623, in finalize_objects
    self._reconstruct_all_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 642, in _reconstruct_all_models
    self._reconstruct_model(model_id, model, layers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 689, in _reconstruct_model
    config, created_layers={layer.name: layer for layer in layers})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py", line 1295, in reconstruct_from_config
    process_node(layer, node_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py", line 1243, in process_node
    output_tensors = layer(input_tensors, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 965, in __call__
    input_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1104, in _functional_construction_call
    inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 834, in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
    return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 875, in _infer_output_signature
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py", line 916, in call
    result = self.function(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 210, in wrapper
    result = dispatch(wrapper, args, kwargs)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

It's a little complicated(lol), appreciate for your help.

Comment: Please see how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are saving it in one format and trying to read it as another.

ModelCheckpoint callback saves the tf model in checkpoint format and tf.keras.models.load_model('model') reads in savedModel format.

In case you want to stick to checkpoint format, use model.load_weights(checkpoint_path) to load the weights or if you want to switch to saved model format use model.save('saved_model/my_model') when saving the model and it should work fine.

Overriding get_config() is only required to save in hdf5 format. Please refer "Saving custom objects" in https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load

Comment: sorry, the problem remains. I used `model.save` but the situation doesn't change. Also, I checked the **ModelCheckpoint**, when set **save_weights_only** False, it will call `model.save()` function.

Comment: Can you add a simple model to reproduce the error?